# How to apply increase function after label_replace?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

We have this counter metric: `http_server_requests_seconds_count`

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{instance="localhost:8080", method="GET", outcome="SUCCESS", status="200", uri="/actuator/health"}       20
http_server_requests_seconds_count{instance="localhost:8080", method="GET", outcome="SUCCESS", status="201", uri="/abc/xyz"}   50
```

We want to write a promql/grafana-ql to create a chart showing how http_server_requests hit at a time range by `status`. It can be done easily:

```
sum(increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count)[$__interval]) by (status)
```

It will create 2 time series on Grafana because we have `status="200"` and `status="201"`

But now requirement changed. We want to `sum() by` 2xx (200, 201,...), 4xx (400, 401, 403,...) and 5xx (500, 502, 503,...):

```
sum(increase(label_replace(http_server_requests_seconds_count, "status_new", "${1}xx", "status", "(2|3|4|5)(.{2})")[$__interval])) by (status_new)
```

But it is not working:

```
Error executing query: invalid parameter "query": 1:114: parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors
```

How can we archive this requirement? Please help! I really need any answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `label_replace` over the result of `increase`:

```
sum(
 label_replace(
  increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count[$__interval]),
  "status_new",  "${1}xx",
  "status",      "(2|3|4|5)(.{2})"
 )
) by (status_new)
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) syntax like this:

```
sum(increase(label_replace(http_server_requests_seconds_count, "status_new", "${1}xx", "status", "(2|3|4|5)(.{2})")[$__interval : ])) by (status_new)
```

(or maybe `[$__interval : 1s]`). But I would not recommend this for this or any other situation, of using functions before `increase` or other similat functions unless you are sure it's in fact needed.